# PHP remember me on multiple computers and browsers

Tags: php, cookies, remember-me

I want my users to be able to login to use remember me cookies across multiple computers and browsers as detailed here: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/secure-persistent-logins-on-multiple-computers/94989/2

I store the ip adress and user agent in my database, but when the client's browser is updated the user agent changes too and they can't use their cookie anymore. Should I just include the name of their browser instead and in that case how do I get just the name?

This is how I retrieve the user agent currently:

```
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

Comment: In my database.

Comment: Where I work, we are about 5000 and we all access the Internet on one single IP address, and we have to use the company's designated browser.  So that would break whatever you are trying to do right?

Comment: @Nic3500 Yes it would, thanks for pointing that out, do you have any suggestions to solve this?

Comment: What is your objective?  You want a user to login once on computer 1, and then stay logged in if they access your site on computer 2?  Besides the user using some auto-login tool (like browsers do, or something else) on the client's side, nothing you can do will provide that type of service, securely and reliably, IMHO.  You cannot guarantee it's the same user, unless he logs in again.

Comment: Actually, I don't think your situation would be that relevant to my problem in particular because accounts are personal. I just want users to be able to login at the same time on different browsers or on their computer and phone for example.

Comment: Well look at it this way.  Google, Amazon, Yahoo, ... do not do that.  They all require you to login each time you change device.  Some provide some centralized single sign-on, but you cannot guarantee that it is the same user on a another device, until he logs in on that said device, at least once.  They can then save their login credentials to "automate" login, but that is not done server side.

Comment: There's really no reliable, secure way to do this. Even using the IP + user agent is not secure, since there can be multiple accounts on the same computer (e.g. a family that shares a desktop computer, but each has their own account).

Comment: @Nic3500 I think we're misunderstanding each other. I just don't want to log the user out on his other devices and I want to enable him to have remember me cookies on multiple devices and browsers. That's what Facebook achieves, right?

Comment: How do I just get the name of the browser and not the version?

Comment: Ah, so you want to allow users to login many times and not be kicked out if they log again from another device?

Comment: @Nic3500 Exactly

Comment: I know I can do this and just get the name: 

get_browser(null, true)["browser"]

But people say it's slow, it might be a bit overkill just to get the browser name.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this is the best solution from: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/secure-persistent-logins-on-multiple-computers/94989/4
When they login, store this data:

```
$user_id = $userid;
$token = sha1($a_salt . uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
$ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$time = time();
```

Store token in a cookie also. Now when they try to autologin:

```
$token = $_COOKIE['token'];
```

SQL Query Condition `WHERE token='$token' AND user_agent='$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] JOIN users ON id=user_id`

You can optionally check that the IP's match, and set an expire time as well.

Comment: I'm not just reposting the question here, I had a problem with the solution and I don't see how this solves that problem. Try reading my question again.